# why ngMaterial cause Openlayer map stop render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openlayers-3

[image]

Sundenly my map stop working so I start tracking down what could be. As you see my controller is almost empty, only leave the function to stop one `not found` error.  So there is not any error on the console

Finally if I remove `ngMaterial` my map start working again

```
var app5 = angular.module("app", ['ui.grid', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache']);

app5.controller('eventCtrl', ["$scope",
   function ($scope) {
       $scope.updateCarsDB = function (source) {
           }
   }]);
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I realize if move the `ng-app` in a different div where the `map` div isnt a child, start working again. The problem is there are other childs wont have access to the angular controllers.

```
<div id="mainContainer" ng-app="app" ng-controller="eventCtrl" >
   <div id="leftTree"></div> 
   <div id="map"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>  // if I move ng-app="app" here map start working
</div>
```

Comment: Any thoughts on what might be the problem, because I came across this issue today with ngMaterial 1.1.1 and Openlayers 3.19.0.

Comment: @kirilv I realize was a javascript error in other place making the code for showing map didnt run. Check your browser console.

Comment: The console does not show any errors in my case. I have a problem with the imageloadstart/end events (for an image source) not being fired.